# objective-c #import whole framework or only needed file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, import

When I'm using big frameworks like the Three20 Framework, 
I always have the choice whether to #import the whole framework or to #import only the single file of it i'd need.

I guess there's a difference in compilation-overhead since it has to open all files of the framework, but is there also a run-time difference? like bigger memory-usage? Or does the compiler-optimization already remove everything that's not needed?

And if I use the same framework pretty much in every class I use, is it recommended to include the framework in the prefix file instead of every single class?

Greetings
Infinite :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a compilation difference, yes: including everything will take longer to compile. But there shouldn't be a run-time difference.

Your idea of including the framework in the prefix is a good one for frameworks you're going to be using throughout. However, there is a catch, which is that if you change something in that framework your **entire** codebase will have to be recompiled.

Comment: I am not arguing ,but won't he require to implement some delegate methods for the classes he does not desire to use? As some of the framework class files may contain delegates to be implemented in its child classes?

Comment: You only need to implement delegate methods for objects you *create* - if you're just importing header files, this shouldn't be necessary. This is certainly true for the framework we're talking about here, Three20.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance hit in runtime. No matter how many frameworks or files you import, if you don't use whichever classes they won't affect the resultant bytecode when you compile. The compiler doesn't even optimize anything; unused classes just "aren't there" at all.

Include the framework in the precompiled header file if you're sure it's going to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You footprint won't be any different unless you actually use the classes however I prefer to be more frugal with my headers, only including the ones I need. If I need a lot from the same library (like Three20) then you can add the whole reference.

Only include headers in the prefix that don't change much, but it will speed up compilation greatly.